# Best Practice To Handle List Names During Serialization

Tags: c#, list, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a list of objects that I return via a WebAPI and create from the same WebApi.  If they are part of another class then I can simply decorate it with a DataContract and all works well.

```
public class ParentClass()
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Children", Namespace = "http://schemas.blah.blah"]
    public List<ChildClass> Children
}
```

The problem arises when I am returning a List directly.  When I do this I lose the DataContract Name and Namespace.

I can create another class

```
[DataContract(Name = "Children", Namespace = "http://schemas.blah.blah"]
public class ChildrenList : List<ChildClass>
{
}
```

and change my parent class to

```
public class ParentClass()
{
    public ChildrenList Children
}
```

which solves the issue but creates many more.  The first is that I lose the ability to do

```
ChildrenList results = getchildrenlistfromsomemethod();
results = results.OrderByDescending(p => p.Rank).ToList();
```

Which I could do with a pure list.  Also it is bad practice to extend a list.  I can fix this by extended from a Collection but then I still have the above problem plus I lose the AddRange() method.

My Questions are

1)Is there a simple way to make a List of a certain type always serialize to a certain name and namespace?

2)Is extending the List the best option and I'm simply stuck between converting to a list, performing orderby, groupby etc.... then adding the items back into a new extended list in a foreach loop. (Seems costly)

3)Have I missed a really obvious and easy way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Trying declaring you List with a backing field:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "Children", Namespace = @"http://schemas.blah.blah"])
    private ChildClass _children;

    public List<ChildClass> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { _children = value }
    }
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as the serializer would look at the public field.  And even if it did work it would be perfect inside the parent class but if I do a...  Return new List<Childclass> ... There's nowhere to set the declaration.